# Why is a variable being assigned to a value AFTER the value has been modified when I've assigned it before it's been modified

Tags: javascript, p5.js

```js
let Text = [];
let textsize = 10;
let Total_Character = 0;
let Ypos = 100;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
}

function keyPressed() {

  //All the characters which I DON'T want in the text, and their keycode

  // 8 = BackSpace, 17 = Control, 13 = Enter(NotDone), 16 = SHIFT, 18 = ALT, 20 = CAPS LOCK, 9 = TAB, 27 = ESCAPE, 45 = INSERT, 46 = DELETE, 33 = PAGE UP, 34 = PAGE DOWN, 36 = HOME, 35 = END, 144 = NUM LOCK, 91 = WINDOWS, 173 = F1, 174 = F2, 175 = F3, 177 = F4, 179 = F5, 176 = F6, 118 = F7, 91 = F8, 38 = UP ARROW, 39 = RIGHT ARROW, 40 = DOWN ARROW, 37 = LEFT ARROW

  //All the Values I don't want in my text writer (Such as "Media Volume Down")
  if (keyCode != 8 && keyCode != 17 && keyCode != 16 && keyCode != 18 && keyCode != 20 && keyCode != 9 && keyCode != 27 && keyCode != 45 && keyCode != 46 && keyCode != 33 && keyCode != 34 && keyCode != 36 && keyCode != 35 && keyCode != 144 && keyCode != 91 && keyCode != 173 && keyCode != 174 && keyCode != 175 && keyCode != 177 && keyCode != 179 && keyCode != 176 && keyCode != 118 && keyCode != 91 && keyCode != 38 && keyCode != 39 && keyCode != 40 && keyCode != 37) {
    //Only true if you press a key that is NOT one of the keycodes listed above, it pushes the key into the Text array (Not to be confused with `text` function)
    Text.push(key)
  }
}

function draw() {
  background(220);

  Total_Character = Text.length;

  //Changes all the different one character strings in the array to one large string
  for (var i = 0; i < Text.length - 1; i++) {
    Text[0] += Text[1];
    Text.splice(1)
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < Text.length; i++) {
    //Displays the text
    textSize(textsize)
    text(Text[i], textWidth(Text[i]) / 2, Ypos);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/p5@1.3.1/lib/p5.js"></script>
```

The `Total_Character` variable always is "1" unless nothing is typed. This part makes sense because the `Total_Character` is the length of the text, and I make the length of the text always 1 large string. The part I need help understanding is why is it "1" I'm assigning `Total_Character` to the length of the text **BEFORE** I change the length of the text, so shouldn't it be the total number of characters? Why is it being defined after the text array is modified?

BTW I included a good portion of my program to give people a feel of what I'm trying to accomplish here. I could've NOT included the code underneath `keyPressed()` but I felt it would make it easier to understand my program as a whole, and when you run it with the snippet tool, it'll work in the Snippet tool. You can completely ignore everything underneath that because it won't particularly affect this question.

Comment: `Text.length` is the length of the array, not the length of the string in the array.

Comment: BTW, your loop could simply be `Text[0] = Text.join('');`

Comment: You want `Total_Character = Text[0].length` after you combine all the strings.

Comment: @Barmar you should post the comments as an aswer so it can be voted/marked as a solution and easily spotted in the future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting the length of the array, not the length of the string in the array.

After you combine all the elements of `Text` into a single string, there's no need to loop over it. Just display `Text[0]`.

```js
let Text = [];
let textsize = 10;
let Total_Character = 0;
let Ypos = 100;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
}

function keyPressed() {

  //All the characters which I DON'T want in the text, and their keycode

  // 8 = BackSpace, 17 = Control, 13 = Enter(NotDone), 16 = SHIFT, 18 = ALT, 20 = CAPS LOCK, 9 = TAB, 27 = ESCAPE, 45 = INSERT, 46 = DELETE, 33 = PAGE UP, 34 = PAGE DOWN, 36 = HOME, 35 = END, 144 = NUM LOCK, 91 = WINDOWS, 173 = F1, 174 = F2, 175 = F3, 177 = F4, 179 = F5, 176 = F6, 118 = F7, 91 = F8, 38 = UP ARROW, 39 = RIGHT ARROW, 40 = DOWN ARROW, 37 = LEFT ARROW

  //All the Values I don't want in my text writer (Such as "Media Volume Down")
  if (keyCode != 8 && keyCode != 17 && keyCode != 16 && keyCode != 18 && keyCode != 20 && keyCode != 9 && keyCode != 27 && keyCode != 45 && keyCode != 46 && keyCode != 33 && keyCode != 34 && keyCode != 36 && keyCode != 35 && keyCode != 144 && keyCode != 91 && keyCode != 173 && keyCode != 174 && keyCode != 175 && keyCode != 177 && keyCode != 179 && keyCode != 176 && keyCode != 118 && keyCode != 91 && keyCode != 38 && keyCode != 39 && keyCode != 40 && keyCode != 37) {
    //Only true if you press a key that is NOT one of the keycodes listed above, it pushes the key into the Text array (Not to be confused with `text` function)
    Text.push(key)
  }
}

function draw() {
  background(220);

  Total_Character = Text.length;

  //Changes all the different one character strings in the array to one large string
  Text[0] = Text[0].join('');
  Text.splice(1)

  //Displays the text
  textSize(textsize)
  text(Text[0], textWidth(Text[0]) / 2, Ypos);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/p5@1.3.1/lib/p5.js"></script>
```

Comment: Just wanted to mention Text.join no longer works and https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/join is what works now.